# Working with libraries in Xcode (i.e. ImageMagick, AdMob) include in project or link?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

*(This may have been asked many times before but I'm not seeing it in the suggested questions/search)*

Assuming I have 3rd party code libraries like ImageMagick and AdMob which I may use in multiple iOS projects, is it "better" to link to them or to include them in the project?

I'm using XCode with git. In one project I have included them so they are all under source control. In another project they are linked and I am getting "?" (question mark) icons next to all the library files. Confusing.

Comment: "to link to them or to include them" - do you use these words in their C-related sense? If so, you should probably do both: including the headers and linking against the library.

Comment: @H2CO3 - no, I mean include as in the files are copied into the project directory compared to linking to the files somewhere else on the HD.

Answer (score 1):

My honest suggestion for using 3rd party libraries would be to use CocoaPods for as many as you can get your hands on. Which there is a good chance all would be available.

Reasons why CocoaPod inclusion is better:

- Easy to add and remove from project
- Automatic linkage to your project
- Easy to update after including

Drawbacks to CocoaPod use:

- Doesn't help you if your library isn't included
- You don't want to use the newly created xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj

The reasons not to use them are pretty weak, and I will admit to be biased in favor of them. I have had to work with lots of static libraries and frameworks, most of which are created in house. CocoaPods has made sharing, maintaining, and installing libraries a piece of cake. So please consider using them in your project.

If CocoaPods aren't your thing or not an option, linking against the library or framework is probably second best. If you drag and drop into your project (while easy) makes updating later kind of a pain. Dynamic linking allows you to swap them out from the file directory without having to change anything in your Xcode project. It requires a bit more finesse to get set up, but ultimately will be better for the long haul. IMO anyway.

Comment: Hadn't heard of CocoaPods before. Will check it out.

Comment: You won't regret it. It's been a lifesaver for me at work as well as personal projects.